# Using grep to display second character in string?

Tags: command-line, grep, awk

I have a string that is always 3 characters... the first one and the last one are always the same.

example:

▁▅█

Is there a simple way to only display the one in the middle? (which is the only one that changes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, try doing this, and pick your preferred method =) :

With [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
echo "ixi" | grep -oP "^.\K."
```

With [cut](/questions/tagged/cut):

```
echo "ixi" | cut -c2
```

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *parameter expansion* :

```
x='ixi'; echo ${x:1:1}
```

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
echo "ixi" | sed 's/.\(.\)./\1/'
```

or

```
echo "ixi" | sed 's/\(^.\|.$\)//g'
```

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
echo "ixi" | perl -lne 'print $& if /^.\K./'
```

With [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby):

```
echo "ixi" | ruby -ne 'print $_.split(//)[1]'
```

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
echo 'ixi' | awk '{split($0, a, ""); print a[2]}'
```

With [python](/questions/tagged/python):

```
echo "ixi" | python -c 'print list("'$(cat)'")[1]'
```

or

```
python -c 'import sys; print list(sys.argv[1])[1]' ixi
```

#### NOTE

- `\K` restart the match to zero (see `pcre` doc)
- `$(cat)` in python is a shell hack to get `STDIN`

Comment: +1 for the nice use of `grep`.

Comment: Added the sortest one : `cut`

Comment: loved that grep

Answer (score 1):

︙
or

```
echo "ixi" | awk '{print substr($0,2,1)}'
```

or

```
expr "ixi" : '.\(.\).'
```

Answer (score 1):

For variety, here's one way with `dd`:

```
echo ixi | dd bs=1 skip=1 count=1 2>/dev/null
```

If your grep doesn't support perl (`-P`), you could do it like this:

```
echo ixi | grep -o . | sed -n 2p
```

These alternatives only work for one-line input.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this way, by using the looking around technique,
so the second char "x" following the examples above using "ixi",

```
echo ixi | grep -oP "(?<=^.)."
```